# Why doesn't my 'didTap marker' function work?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have been building a Google Maps iOS app and somehow my 'didTap marker' function does not work. If I tap on a marker on the map, the whole view simply just gets dragged off to left, but no code gets run. Otherwise, the print functions below would work. Where might cause this problem?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker){
    var lat: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.latitude
    var lng: CLLocationDegrees = marker.position.longitude
    var formattedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat,longitude: lng)
    print("markersArray is \(markersArray)")
    print("formattedCoordinate is \(formattedCoordinate)")
    markersArray = markersArray.filter({ !(($0.latitude == formattedCoordinate.latitude) && ($0.longitude == formattedCoordinate.longitude)) })
}
```

Comment: That's a delegate method no? Did you set the delegate for the mapView?

Comment: It's a delegate method. I don't know how to set the delegate for mapView, I thought it was already recognised as a delegate method therefore should function.

Comment: Edit: I set the delegate for mapView previously, to self

Comment: `googleMapView.delegate = self` where googleMapView is instance of GMSMapView

Comment: within the code block above, or outside it? I did that in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 6):

You need to set delegate for mapview.

set delegate in `viewDidLoad`

```
myGMSMapView.delegate = self
```

then use this method

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        <#code#>
    }
```

Comment: So I always need to add the return type? I have several functions that work without specifying their return type.

Comment: Yeah obviously for the delegate methods you need to add return type

Answer (score -1):

Add this delegate in your class.

```
GMSMapViewDelegate
```

Now, this will be your marker action.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    mapView.delegate = self

    print("You tapped : \(marker.position.latitude),\(marker.position.longitude)") 
}
```